# How to accumulate matches when querying multiple tables in SQLite?

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, group-by, inner-join

Table1

```
ID     Name     CourseID
1     Course 1   4002
2     Course 2   2342
3     Course 3   2410
```

Table2

```
CourseID ProfName
4002     John
2342     bob 
2410     Bill
4002     Hannah
2342     Cyrus
```

When I try

```
SELECT ID, Name, CourseID, ProfName 
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.CourseID = Table2.CourseID
```

I get multiple instances for the same CourseID returned  such that when I print it out

"1, Course 1, 4002, John"  and

"1, Course 1, 4002, Hannah" are two different outputs.

I would like them to be of the form

"1, Course 1, 4002, **John and Hannah**"

Not sure how to alter my SQL query to make this happen?

Comment: And what if you had more than 2?

Comment: i'd want to display the full list e.g "John, Hannah, Sarah, Joshua" etc

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

Use string aggregation:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.courseid, group_concat(t2.profname, ' and ') profnames
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.courseid = t2.courseid 
group by t1.id, t1.name, t1.courseid
```

Note that this uses *standard* join syntax (`join ... on ...`) rather than implicit joins (with a comma in the `from` clause): this old-school syntax should not be used in new code.

You could also use a subquery:

```
select t1.*
    (
        select group_concat(t2.profname, ' and ') 
        from table2 t2
        where t2.courseid = t1.courseid
    ) profnames
from table1 t1
```

Unrelated note: `and` does not seem like a great choice for a list separator: if there are more than two values, the result is not correct English. A more usual choice is, for example, the comma (`,`) - that's the default separator in SQLite and most other databases.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want commas between most of the names and `and` only for the last one.  That would be:

```
select t1.*, t2.profnames
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.courseid,
             (group_concat(case when seqnum > 1 then profname end) || ', and '
              max(case when seqnum = 1 then profname end)
             ) as profnames
      from (select t2.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by courseid order by profname desc) as seqnum,
            from table2 t2
           ) t2
      group by t2.courseid
     ) t2
     on t1.courseid = t2.courseid;
```